# Can't find or create new Storyboard file in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to use the Storyboard files in XCode but I can't find it while creating the project
and when I downloaded a storyboard sample I couldn't open the storyboard file it opens as an XML file
Any help.

Comment: whats the version of xcode that you are using?

Comment: I can't check it now. but I think it is 4.0  , Is there any restrictions, I am using a free ios developer account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you are using an old version of xcode, you will have to download xcode 4.2+ version

your current version of xcode is not capable of understanding storyboard files, and since a storyboard is an xml file, its opening it as so

Comment: Is my free ios developer account will allow me to download the new version?

Comment: yes xcode is free in the appstore, open macs appstore and search for xcode you can get xcode 4.3.3

Answer (score 1):

Storyboards have been available since iOS 5 SDK. If you are using an older version, then you should probably update. Download it here: https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/